# nao installation NaoQI Python SDK

Tags: ros, naoqi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,everyone!
I'm fresh new in ROS. I have been followinig the tutorials. When I was tring to install ros for nao "Installing ROS on a remote PC to control Nao", I got stuck. How can I get the NaoQi Python SDK? I tried to search on google,but I didn't get it.
I installed the ros-hydro-desktop-full. I wondered if the SDK is integrated already.

best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106266/nao-installation-naoqi-python-sdk/) by [Menglord](https://answers.ros.org/users/9206/menglord/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The NaoQI SDK is only available from Aldebaran Robotics and you usually get access to it by buying a Nao robot. You may also be able to get a trial version at https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/ but I'm not sure if that only includes Choregraphe and not the SDK.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0